# can't use assignment to construct an object using derived shared_ptr

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

This is the code. I think it shows my question. So how can I make it work?

```
#include <memory>

struct base {
  virtual ~base();
};

struct derived : public base {};

struct A {
  A(std::shared_ptr<base> x) {}
};

int main() {
  std::shared_ptr<derived> data = std::make_shared<derived>();
  A a1(data);  // ok
  A a2 = data; // not ok
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the error at not ok?

Comment: @273K candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'shared_ptr<derived>' to 'shared_ptr<base>' for 1st argument

Comment: Which compiler are you using ? And also please [edit] and post the exact error message you get, in your question.

Comment: @wohlstad I'm using the latest version of clang. I compiled it myself. The command is "clang++   -g -O0 -Wall -o main.o -c main.cpp"

Comment: You can try to make `data` a `std::shared_ptr<base>` (it can still be initialized with `std::make_shared<derived>`).

Comment: The problem is that the copy-initialization requires two conversions; from `std::shared_ptr<derived>` to `std::shared_ptr<base>`, and from `std::shared_ptr<base>` to `A`. `A a2 = A(data);` will work.

Comment: I think that ```A a2 = ``` implicitely requires copy construction (from A&), thus the compiler is looking for a conversion from ```std::shared_ptr<derived>``` rvalue to ```A&```
I think that there is something inside [copy construction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor)
I'll try to find the exact wording.

Comment: Note that `A a2 = data;` is **not** assignment, despite the use of the `=` operator. Creating a new object is **construction**, even with `=`; modifying an existing object with `=` is **assignment**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
A a2 = data; // not ok
```

This doesn't work because the compiler would need to perform two conversions (`shared_ptr<derived>` -> `shared_ptr<base>` -> `A`), but it may only do one implicitly.

To fix it, you can either add an overloaded constructor, if you know `derived`:

```
A(std::shared_ptr<derived> x) : A(static_cast<std::shared_ptr<base>>(x)) {}
```

or you can store your pointer as `shared_ptr<base>` to begin with:

```
std::shared_ptr<base> data = std::make_shared<derived>();
```